# How to rebuild derived plugins after new entities are installed?

Tags: 8, caching, testing, plugins

I have a problem with a stale plugin-derivatives cache in a kernel test:

```
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->installConfig(['my_module', 'my_module_test']);
  }
```

The `my_module_test` module installs new entities that *should* produce derived plugins, but when my test class tries to instantiate these plugins, they are not found.

It works if I explicitly call `$this->container->get('{my_plugin_manager}')->clearCachedDefinitions()` after `installConfig()`, so it's definitely a stale plugin cache. But I'm worried this problem might happen elsewhere. Is there some way to tag the plugin cache with `{my_entity_type}_list` so it gets invalidated by new entities? Or do I simply need to invalidate it explicitly whenever I do something that creates new entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should do that.

Module install is not really a problem as all plugins are invalidated then anyway, but entities can also be changed in the UI.

See \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::postSave() for an example that does that in core.

Comment: Thanks, the entity's ::postSave is a great idea; so far I had this logic in the form save, which doesn't cover non-interactive stuff.